# Background color appearing on h1 tag when I did not set it CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to add a `h1` tag into my header `div` tag, but a background color keeps appearing when I did not set it in the css and I cannot figure out why and how to remove it.

```html
<div id="header_top">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
<div id="navbar_top"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main_content"></div>
    <div id="side_bar"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #0F1012;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#header_top {
    background-color: #222325;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #0F1012;
}
#header_top h1 {
    color: white;
}
#navbar_top {
    background-color: #222325;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0da85wrn/)

Comment: I suggest using jsFiddle to show the code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: As @Koralarts said.. You it's better if you post a jsfiddle. So [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8sr0qnzb/) is the link to the code you gave us.

Comment: Thanks, i will use that from now on. I didn't know about that until now.

Comment: @R4zerx420 Note you don't have to post the code in jsFiddle. The requirement is including the code in the question itself. However, a live demo (e.g. jsfiddle, codepen, dabblet, ...) is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code :

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #0F1012;
}
```

That basically sets the background to each element on the page. Including your `h1` tag.
Remove the `background-color` and you should be fine.

Comment: Omg..Thanks very much! that seems to have done it. I feel so stupid right now that i didn't notice that. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @R4zerx420 if the issue is solved always mark the question as a solution so as others know the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what do you mean. But probably you have to switch this:

```
* {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #0F1012;
}
```

to this:

```
body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #0F1012;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ps9f38bq/).